# Express.js unuse/remove vhost?

Tags: node.js, express

**context**

I have a server with a single IP and I have some virtual domains running on the same port using express.vhost.

```
app.listen (80);     
app.use (express.vhost ('www.example.com', 
                         require('./vhosts/example/app.js').app));    
app.use (express.vhost ('www.another.com', 
                         require('./vhosts/another/app.js').app));
```

*app.js example*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello Virtual Domain');
});
module.exports.app = app;
```

**question**

How I can release one of these virtual domains without restarting the application?

some kind of

```
app.use (var example = express.vhost ('www.example.com', 
                             require('./vhosts/example/app.js').app));
 // LATER
app.unuse(example);
```

I'm trying to outsource the administration of the vhosts and developing a tool for someone else can. This application monitors a json with a list of virtual domains file. I can easily add virtual domains but I need a way to remove them without restarting the service itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Express 4**

You'll need the `vhost` module since `Express 4` no longer depends on `Connect`.

With `Express 4` you could create a router that handles all of your vhosts and isolate your vhosts from the rest of your routes.

```
var vhost = require('vhost');

var vhostRouter = express.Router();
vhostRouter.use(vhost('www.example.com', exampleApp));
```

You can then splice `vhostRouter.stack` to remove a vhost.

**vhostRouter.stack**

```
[ { handle: [Function: vhost],
    name: 'vhost',
    params: undefined,
    path: undefined,
    keys: [],
    regexp: { /^\/?(?=\/|$)/i fast_slash: true },
    route: undefined } ]
```

If you are using the apps router you'll have to splice from `app._router.stack`

---

**Express 3**

`req.use` pushes middleware onto `app.stack`. Simply splice the vhost from `app.stack`

---

Note: This feature probably doesn't exist by design. I am not sure why. You should be aware though, as it is not supported and the behavior could change in a future version.